# Inconsistency regarding the spatial trajectory of a particle subject to a given force field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, kinematics, vectors

I have recently been trying to formalize a mathematical method (for my own recreational purposes) to work out the shape of the path that a particle traces out in space if we are given the resultant forces acting on it, for all components. However, I seem to have run into quite a challenge - the algebra that follows seems to imply that $x$-component of the particle's velocity is zero for all points along it's path, and for every type of force, which is clearly false.

I have also tried using Lagrangian mechanics\variational principles to formulate a similar ODE that models the path, but the fact that there is an inconsistency at all between these two approaches must mean that one of these methods is wrong, and is leading me to incorrect conclusions when analyzing the kinematics of more specific systems, which concerns me greatly as I am a 2nd-year university student.

My "classical mechanics" approach goes like this:

To deduce the trajectory of a particle of mass $m$ moving within a given force field, $\vec{F} = \Big (F_x(x,y),F_y(x,y) \Big)$, (i.e. the vertical height above the $x$-axis, $y(x)$), we can apply the chain rule: $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{ \frac{dy}{dt}}{ \frac{dx}{dt}} = \frac{v_y}{v_x}$, where $v_x,v_y$ represent the vector components of the particle's velocity.

By the work-energy theorem, we have $\displaystyle mv_x^2 = mu_x^2 + 2\int_{0}^{x} F_x(s,y(s)) \space ds $, and $\displaystyle mv_y^2 = mu_y^2 + 2\int_{0}^{y(x)} F_y(s,y(s)) \space \frac{dy}{ds} ds$ (a path integral), where $u_x, u_y$ are the vector components of the particle's initial velocity.

$\Longrightarrow \displaystyle (y'(x))^2 =\frac{\displaystyle mu_y^2 + 2\int_{0}^{y(x)} F_y(s,y(s)) \space \frac{dy}{ds} ds}{\displaystyle mu_x^2 + 2\int_{0}^{x} F_x(s,y(s)) \space ds}$

Multiplying through by the denominator and differentiating both sides of the resulting equation with respect to $x$, we obtain $F_y = mu_x^2 y''(x) + y'(x)F_x + 2y''(x) \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} F_x(s) \space ds $ (1)

But since $\displaystyle F_x = \frac{|\vec{F}|v_x}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}} = \vec{F} \cdot \hat{x}$, and $\displaystyle F_y = \frac{|\vec{F}|v_y}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}}= \vec{F} \cdot \hat{y} $, we have that $\frac{F_y}{F_x} = \frac{v_y}{v_x} = y'(x)$, and so the equation $F_y = mu_x^2 y''(x) + y'(x)F_x + 2y''(x) \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} F_x(s) \space ds $ (1) simplifies to $\displaystyle mu_x^2 + 2\int_{0}^{x} F_x(s) \space ds =0$, or $v_x(x) = 0$, which is a nonsensical result!

It should be noted, however, that equation (1) seems to yield the correct differential equation governing the parabolic trajectory of a thrown projectile (subject to zero air drag): $F_x = 0$, $F_y = -mg \Longrightarrow y''(x) = -\frac{g}{u_x^2} = -\frac{g}{u^2 \cos^2(\theta_0)} $. I believe there must be a misunderstanding of the physics here on my part, perhaps when trying to work out the components of velocity in terms of the respective components of forces (though, as outlined in a comment here, this still eludes me as to why I'm wrong), or of kinematics in general (which is slightly more troubling).

Comment: a = F / m should give the correct trajectory for any force field? If the force is arbitrary & could be discontinuous at some places, analytic solution as a function of time might be hard to come by.

Comment: My apologies - I meant to say that the field is given as $\vec{F} = \Big (F_x(x,y),F_y(x,y) \Big)$.  My confusion stems from the fact that I somehow ended up with the result $v_x = 0$ for any force field and particle trajectory $y(x)$,  regardless of whether it is smooth/not smooth or 'nice', which is clearly not true in general. I was wondering whether this is due to an algebraic blunder or an incorrect application of Newton's second law.

Comment: The way i would do this is by double integrating **a** while letting **F** dictate the acceleration at every point. But other users should hopefully be able to point out where the error lies in your algebra.

Comment: Saying that $F_y/F_x = v_y/v_x$ is equivalent to saying that the directions of $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{v}$ are the same at all times.  This isn't necessarily true (though I don't think that's the source of the contradiction.)

Comment: This is not a homework question. What kind of a teacher/instructor would set this as a graded assignment?

Comment: @appletax13 Questions aren't closed because they may have been assigned. Please read the whole closure reason and links therein

Comment: @BioPhysicist I'm re-editing the question now. Do let me know if it is still an unsuitable query for this site

Comment: I think you're right, nice catch. But I (embarrassingly) forget to apply Leibniz's integral rule when differentiating both sides and so my mistake doesn't seem to carry over to the final result, otherwise there would be a $y'^2$ lingering around there somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You statement
$$ 
mv_x^2 = mu_x^2 + 2\int_{0}^{x} F_x(s,y(s)) \space ds 
$$
is false. You seem to be assuming that you can resolve the kinetic energy into $x$ and $y$ components. KE is a scalar and does not have components.

The work energy theorem says that
$$
\frac 12m |{\bf v}_{\rm final}|^2 - \frac 12m |{\bf v}_{\rm initial}|^2= \int {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r}
$$ is *one* equation in any number of dimensions.

In response to your comment I need to point out that
$$
\frac{d v_x}{dt}= \frac {dx}{dt}\frac{d v_x}{dx}= v_x\frac{d v_x}{dx}
$$
applies only for one dimensional motion. In higher dimensions $v_x$ is no longer just a function of $x$. The  attempted generalization via the partial derivative chain rule
$$
\frac{\partial v^x}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} \frac{\partial v_x}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} \frac{\partial v_x}{\partial z}\\
= v_x \frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x} + v_y \frac{\partial v_x}{\partial y}+v_z \frac{\partial v_x}{\partial z}
$$
is doomed because $v_x$ is a function only of $t$ and not of $x,y,z$  separately. So the other partial do not exist.

Comment: I'm not sure how that statement implies that KE is a vector. But I do know that force is a vector, and so it's $x$-component should be given by (do correct me if I'm wrong) $\displaystyle F_x = m\frac{dv_x}{dt} = mv_x \frac{dv_x}{dx}$.  Integrating both sides of this equation with respect to the path parameter $s$ and rearranging for $v_x = \vec{v} \cdot \hat{x}$ yields the statement in question.

Comment: I'll add another bit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to append your answer. However, I'm still a bit lost considering that $y$ is still a function of $x$ in my problem, and so I'm not sure how I would take the partial derivative of $v_x$ wrt to $y$ if $v_x$ is only a function of $x$ (and technically a function of $y(x)$, which in this case is the 1D parameterization of a path and so depends on $x$ only, I think).

Comment: Perhaps another way to say it, is that although $y$ can be a function of $x$ is the path has a suitable shape, ithe value of $y$ at a given $x$ depends on $F_y$ so you cannot extract $\dot x^2$ from a knowldge of $F_x$ alone.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. So what would be the full relationship between $\dot{x}^2$, $F_x$ and $F_y$? Thanks

Comment: The only way is to solve the equations of motion. Energy conservation reduces on the $d=$ dimension of space second-order equations to d-1 second-order equations and one first order,  but in the absence of other conservation laws such as angular momentum that reduction is all you get.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your help